# Are there any open source firmware for Internet modems?

Tags: hardware, firmware

I've been playing around with my own router and found DD-WRT as an open source firmware alternative for this kind of device but I can't find something equivalent for modems. Can you recommend something?

Comment: This is off-topic. You might like to ask at [softwarerecs.se] instead.